# Javascript element targeting

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, my javascript skills are about zero so this is probably easy peasy :)

I have a js carousel with a number of slides and each slide has two divs that you can alter between (show/hide) by clicking on two nav-tabs above ("View" and "Read"), and each slide has these nav-tabs. Everything is working fine except for one annoying detail. Each nav-tab has a dynamic js generated active class to indicate which one is currently active. But the current script targets all nav-tabs on every slide at the same time instead of just the one I'm currently viewing. So I want to remove the active class only for the tab that is inside the same element as the other tab that I'm clicking on.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="big-container" id="slide1">
<!-- The tabs -->
    <div class="nav-tabs">
        <span class="nav-tab active">
            <a href="#thumbs">View</a>
        </span>
        <span class="nav-tab">
            <a href="#info">Read</a>
        </span>
    </div>
<!-- The div with info text -->                 
    <div class="project-info hide" id="info">
        Here goes some text
    </div>
<!-- The div with images -->
    <div class="img-thumbs" id="thumbs">
        <img src="some-image.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-tab > a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//stop browser to take action for clicked anchor
 
    //get displaying tab content jQuery selector
    var active_tab_selector = $('span.active > a').attr('href');                    
 
    //find actived navigation and remove 'active' css
    var actived_nav = $('.nav-tabs > span.active');
    actived_nav.removeClass('active');
 
    //add 'active' css into clicked navigation
    $(this).parents('span').addClass('active');
 
    //hide displaying tab content
    $(active_tab_selector).removeClass('active');
    $(active_tab_selector).addClass('hide');
 
    //show target tab content
    var target_tab_selector = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target_tab_selector).removeClass('hide');
    $(target_tab_selector).addClass('active');
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like

```
$(this).parents('.nav-tabs').find('.active').removeClass('active');
```

where

```
$(this).parents('.nav-tabs')
```

goes upwards and finds the `.nav-tabs` that you're in, then

```
.find('.active').removeClass('active');
```

goes downards finding any `.active` and removing them.

Comment: That took care of the tabs, but for some reason ruined the rest of the script, since now the show/hide divs function just works for the first slide but not for the others...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('nav-tabs').find('.active').removeClass('active');
```

As the other answer indicates, .parents would also work. I slightly prefer to use closest over parents when I only expect to find one parent (even though it's a little slower, IIRC). It's not likely in your case, but in this case parents would look for all ancestors with the .nav-tabs class, so if somehow you had nested .nav-tabs, you might get unexpected behavior.

Comment: As I replied to thebjorn, both your suggestions work for the tabs, but then the show/hide function for some reason stops working for all slides but the first. I've added some more of the html to give a better understanding of the structure of each slide.